# tablelayout delete tablerow in android

Tags: android, tablelayout, tablerow

```
    final TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableLayout);
    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);


    TextView t2 = new TextView(this);
    t2.setText("test");
    row.addView(t2);

    Button bu = new Button(this);
    bu.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.del);
    bu.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //I need to delete the tablerow
                            //how to do?

        }

    });
    row.addView(bu);

    table.addView(row, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(WC, WC));
```

**
i want to delete tablerow in bu.setOnClickListener
how to do removeViewAt() ,i cant find indexId
**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [removeView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html#removeView%28android.view.View%29) for removing tablerow as:

```
table.removeView(row);
```

**NOTE:** If they don't have unique id then use:

```
table.removeView(rowIndex);
```

and by using `removeViewAt`

```
for(int i = 0, j < table.getChildCount(); i < j; i++){ 
    // then, you can remove the the row you want... 
    // for instance... 
    TableRow row = getChildAt(i); 
    if( something you want to check ) { 
        removeViewAt(i); 
        // or... 
        removeView(row); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: TableRow row = new TableRow(this);  add final, become final TableRow row = new TableRow(this); it work! thanks!