# Removing TableRows programmatically

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I have successfully added a `TableRow` to the `TableLayout`,now I would like to programmatically remove the `TableRow` and add the original row to the `TableLayout`.Here is the code that I use to generate the TableRow:

```
public TableRow getTableRow(String text,String hint,boolean addCollapseOption)
{
    TableRow tr=new TableRow(getBaseContext());
    tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    TextView temp=new TextView(getBaseContext());
    temp.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    temp.setText(text);
    tr.addView(temp);
    tempId="edit_"+count;
    count++;
    EditText edit_temp=new EditText(getBaseContext());
    TableRow.LayoutParams edit_params=new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1f);
    edit_params.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 0);
    edit_temp.setLayoutParams(edit_params);
    edit_temp.setHint(hint);
    tr.addView(edit_temp);
    if(addCollapseOption)
    {
        ImageButton btn_less=new ImageButton(getBaseContext());
        btn_less.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        btn_less.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon_less));
        btn_less.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                shouldCollapse=true;
            }
        });
        tr.addView(btn_less);
                }
    return tr;
}
```

The Activity crashes when I try to add this TableRow to the TableLayout:

```
  TableRow tr=getTableRow("First Name","Enter first name here",true);
```

I guess you cannot remove a View from the Layout and still be able to use the click event in it(that crashes the activity),`layout` and `shouldCollapse` are global variables,if set to true:

```
   if(shouldCollapse)
    {
        layout.removeAllViews();
        layout.addView(originalRow);
    }
```

EDIT:Changing the implementation to use `removeChildAt` does not work:

```
   if(shouldCollapse)
    {
        int childCount=layout.getChildCount();
        for(int i=1;i<childCount;i++)
            layout.removeViewAt(i);
        originalRow.setVisibility(TableRow.VISIBLE);
                    shouldCollapse=false;
    }
```

Now,clicking on the btn_less does absolutely nothing.This is the Logcat's opinion of the problem:

```
    Less clicked
    The value of shouldCollapse true
```

So,this means that even though shouldCollapse is set to true but this method is never called...strange.

Comment: For remove table rows programmatically, see this link: [remove tablerows]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10515963/tablelayout-delete-tablerow-in-android

Comment: @TrushitShah Added new code with `removeChildAt`,decieded to keep child at `0` which would be `originalRow` wouldnt it and just changed it's visibility.Does not work...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to remove the programmatically generated TableRows:

```
  public void onClick(View v)
  {
            final TableRow parent = (TableRow) v.getParent();
            tr.removeView(parent);
  }
```

Or if you want to use this out side the onClick, you must pass the value of *View v* to whatever function it is.